# What is causing these 'unexpected tokens' errors after constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am working on a circuit simulator/pathfinding system, but I keep getting these weird compilation errors. I am not yet that experienced with OO C++ to figure it out myself...

## Object Tree

The objects in my project are implemented in this way:

- **Object**

  - Component

    - Wire
    - Switch
  - Ciruit

My **Object** class is the base class for everything in my project, this is great for debugging by giving everything a name and an id. 
I required that every component needs a Circuit to with (see it as a parent for components). I implemented this by creating a constructor in the Component class that requires a reference to a Circuit object.

At first, everything worked and compiled fine, but when I introduced the Circuit class and when I added a constructor in Component with a Circuit reference parameter, everything went wrong...

**Compilation errors**

Now I keep getting these seemingly random syntax and missing tokens errors. (Intellisense does not mark them?)

The first four errors that pop up are:

`C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'`.

At line 10 of Component.hpp. And at line 12 in file Circuit.hpp.
Both just after the constructor definition. (See in code below)

The next four errors point tot the same locations, but it notes:

`C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'`.

Then, 30 more errors follow, but I think they are a result of these errors, to be sure, here they are:

(Lol, cannot embed image, caused by not having enough reputation, so a link instead...)

[Click here for errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1JZi.png)

**What I tried**

I tried the following:

- Using a reference instead of pointer. (changed `Circuit* c` to `Circuit& c`)
- Removing the name string concationation thing in constructor initializer list. (changed `... : Object(name + "blah")` to `... : Object(name)`)
- Rewriting the whole Visual Studio project to a new Visual Studio project.
- Placing the constructor initializer list in the header file.
- Lots of googling... and not lots of solving...

**How to fix?**

This frustrating problem is stopping me from working further on this project, what is causing it and how do I fix it? I would be pretty happy to know.

#### Object.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using std::string;

class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    Object(string name);
    string name;
    const int id;
    virtual string toString();
private:
    static int currentId;
};
```

#### Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.hpp"

int Object::currentId = 0;

Object::Object() : id(++Object::currentId), name("Object")
{ }

Object::Object(string name) : id(++Object::currentId), name(name)
{ }

string Object::toString()
{
    return name + "#" + std::to_string(id);
}
```

#### Component.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Object.hpp"
#include "Circuit.hpp"

class Component : public Object
{
public:
    Component(std::string name, Circuit* container);
    Circuit *container; // <- Error points to the beginning of this line
};
```

#### Component.cpp

```
#include "Component.hpp"

Component::Component(string name, Circuit* container) : Object(name), container(container)
{ }
```

#### Switch.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Component.hpp"
#include "Wire.hpp"

class Switch : public Component
{
public:
    Switch(string name, Circuit* container, Wire& wire1, Wire& wire2);
    Wire* wire1;
    Wire* wire2;
    void setEnabled(bool enabled);
    bool getEnabled();

private:
    bool enabled;
};
```

#### Switch.cpp

```
Switch::Switch(string name, Circuit* container, Wire& wire1, Wire& wire2) : Component(name + "-Switch", container), wire1(&wire1), wire2(&wire2), enabled(false)
{ }

...
```

#### Circuit.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Object.hpp"
#include "Wire.hpp"

class Circuit : public Object
{
public:
    Circuit(std::string name);
    Wire* powerWire; // <- Error points to the beginning of this line
    bool isPowered(Wire& wire);
    bool getActive();
    void setActive(bool active);
private:
    bool active;
};
```

#### Circuit.cpp

```
#include "Circuit.hpp"
#include "Util.hpp"

Circuit::Circuit(string name) : Object(name + "-Circuit")
{
    active = false;
    powerWire = new Wire(name + "-PowerWire", this);
}

...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't shown `Wire.hpp`, but my guess is that it includes `Component.hpp`, which gives you a cycle in header inclusion (because `Component.hpp` includes `Circuit.hpp`, and `Circuit.hpp` includes `Wire.hpp`).

You will have to replace some of these inclusions with forward declarations to break the cycle.

Comment: That's it! I fixed it by adding a 'forward declaration' to _Circuit_ in Component.hpp. Thank you so mush!